# Google Apps Script Trigger: How to get timer time?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, displayobject

I need to get the timer time of a trigger to show it on a Google Sheet. However, I cannot find the detail.

```
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
     if (triggers[i].getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK) {
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible. But `new Date()` should give you a approx time.

Comment: As an addition to the answer above, you can visit the documentation on ["Working with Dates and Times"](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates).